# Vue.JS computed from VueX Store "is not defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex store which shows up in the vue devtools.

When I try to load data into a computed, I get the message that it is not defined.

```
computed: {
    userData(){
      return this.$store.state.userData
    }
  },
changeActivePage(newPage){
      console.log(newPage);
      if(!this.userData.loggedIn){
      ...
      }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "changeActivePage": "ReferenceError: userData is not defined"
```

Am I overlooking or forgetting something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `changeActivePage()` you must get userData from store like:

```
this.$store.userData.loggedIn
```

Comment: Yep that did work. Although I don't really get why it wouldnt work with the computed